# How to query for an existing 'xinput map-to-output' touchscreen mapping

Tags: xrandr, touchscreen, xinput

Is there a way to identify that a touchscreen has been mapped/limited to a display?

Steps I'm using to map:

1. `xrandr --query` to get the display name
2. `xinput list` to see all the slave devices on the virtual pointer
3. `xinput --list-props {device_id}` to get the device node
4. `udevadm info --query=property --name={device_node}` to check if a property says `ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=1`
5. `xinput map-to-output {device_id} {display_name}` to map/limit touchscreen input to a single monitor

If I walked up to a machine that has had these steps performed, how can I verify that the input from `device_id` was mapped to `display_name`?

Or where can I see that input from `device_id` is limited to screen area X,Y,W,H?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xinput list-props {device_id}` shows all device properties that can be changed and current values.

Check for a property named `Coordinate Transformation Matrix` that has a non-default set of 9 float numbers as a value. The `map-to-output` parameter calculates the CTM for you and sets that property.

Default:

```
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (157): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

After `map-to-output` example:

```
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (157): 0.533333, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.878049, 0.121951, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks!
For anyone trying to associate back to the original display you can:
-Multiply the `screen 0: current {W} x {H}` by the CTM's scaling factor (the 3x3 matrix diagonal) to get the corresponding display's resolution.
-Multiple the `screen 0: current {W} x {H}` by the CTM's translation (the 3x3 matrix last column) to get the corresponding display's positional offset (in the case you have multiple with the same resolution.)

Comment: For the record, resetting the `Coordinate Transformation Matrix` property can be done using: `xinput --set-prop {device-id} {ctm-property-id} 1 0 0   0 1 0    0 0 1`
The last numbers represents the identity matrix, as explained here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation
The `{ctm-property-id}` in @cprn's answer would be `157`. You can check it using `xinput --list-props {input-id}`